# How to check for stability for non-constant controller using Nyquist plots?

Tags: control, stability, nyquist-plot

Let's say I have a unitary feedback system with one unstable (RHP) pole. Now if my \$G_c\$ is a constant, say \$K\$, I know that in order to have stability I should have a single counterclockwise encirclement of \$-\frac1K\$ so that \$Z = N + P\$ becomes \$0\$. Where \$N\$ is the number of encirclements of the point \$-\frac1K\$ and  \$P\$ is the number of unstable poles.

This is because:

$$\frac{GK}{1+GK}$$

is the new transfer function. However, if my \$G_c\$ is \$Ks\$ or \$\frac Ks\$, how can I find the range for \$K\$ using the \$Z = N + P = 0\$ (Nyquist Stability) criteria? In other words, which point do I have to encircle now?